# uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' when handling cloudkit errors

Tags: swift

My app crashed with the following error, i am trying to replicate it but i cant, so could anyone provide some insight as to whats going wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 //all the usual class methods here

 @objc func getData() {
self.array = []
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: “Product”, predicate: predicate)

let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
queryOperation.resultsLimit = 5
queryOperation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
    self.array.append(record)
}
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
    if error != nil{
      cloudkitHelper.request(error: error!, viewController: self). //this line causes the crash

    }
    else{
        if cursor != nil {
            self.askAgain(cursor!)
        }
    }
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
Database.share.publicDB.add(queryOperation)
}

func askAgain(_ cursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor) {
let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor)
queryOperation.resultsLimit = 5

queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {
    record in
    self.array.append(record)
}
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
    if error != nil{
        cloudkitHelper.request
    }
    else{
        if cursor != nil {
            self.askAgain(cursor!)
        }
    }
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
Database.share.publicDB.add(queryOperation)
}
}

class cloudkitHelper: ViewController{
static func request( error:Error, viewController:ViewController) {
    if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
        if ckerror.code == CKError.requestRateLimited {
            let retryInterval = ckerror.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as? TimeInterval
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: retryInterval!, target: self, selector: #selector(self.getData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
        }
        else if ckerror.code == CKError.zoneBusy {
            let retryInterval = ckerror.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as? TimeInterval
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: retryInterval!, target: self, selector: #selector(self.getData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
        }
        else if ckerror.code == CKError.limitExceeded {
            let retryInterval = ckerror.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as? TimeInterval
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: retryInterval!, target: self, selector: #selector(self.getData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
        }
}
```

> 2018-10-17 19:54:41.335517+0100 cloudkitApp[6011:1308502]
>   +[cloudkitApp.cloudkitHelper getData]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x103879c28 2018-10-17 19:54:41.407939+0100
>   cloudkitApp[6011:1308502] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[cloudkitApp.cloudkitHelper getData]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   class 0x103879c28'

Answer (score 1):

Please **read** the error message.

It says that there is no selector `getData` in `cloudkitHelper` which is true. Please name it `CloudkitHelper` according to the naming conventions and to indicate that you are calling a **class** method.

`getData` belongs to `ViewController` and (the target) `self` represents the `CloudkitHelper` class.

Change the `Timer` line(s) to

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: retryInterval!, target: viewController, selector: #selector(getData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Rather than a subclass of `ViewController` an `extension` and instance method is more reasonable. I removed redundant code and used the block based `Timer` API

```
extension ViewController {
    func request( error:Error) {
        if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
            switch ckerror.code {
            case .requestRateLimited, .zoneBusy, .limitExceeded:
                let retryInterval = ckerror.userInfo[CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as! TimeInterval
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: retryInterval, repeats: false) { _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.getData()
                    }
                }
            default: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```